# Track International Airplane Arrival/Departure time

Tags: connecting-flights, timetables

I want to track an airline arrival/departure timings at CDG and New-Delhi, it would help me to plan another connecting flight. Is there a way to track this timings, is it publicly available.

Comment: Do you mean historical data or are you going to do this going forward?

Comment: yes, like last one month historical data ... of flights arrival on cdg airport. i can filter based on airline number or air plane name.

Comment: thanks, i belive that is what i am looking for...